# Differences between webAppAccess.getVariables().getXmlElement("someResults","RowSet") and webAppAccess.getVariables().getXml("someResults","RowSet")

Tags: ibm-rad

I am wondering what does are the differences between:

```
webAppAccess.getVariables().getXmlElement("someResults","RowSet")
```

and

```
webAppAccess.getVariables().getXml("someResults")
```

in `IBM` web experience factory?

Answer (score 2):

When we call getXmlElement("someResults","RowSet") then the IXml variable named "someResults" is searched for the element "RowSet" in it and the same is returned.
The getXml("someResults") returns the full IXml variable.
Here is an eg.
Suppose the IXml variable "someResults" has the following value

```
 <data>
         <RowSet>
            <row>
               <name>row1</name>
             </row>
        </RowSet>
       </data>

**Output for** getXmlElement("someResults","RowSet")
<RowSet>
            <row>
               <name>row1</name>
             </row>
        </RowSet>

**Output for** getXml("someResults")
<data>
         <RowSet>
            <row>
               <name>row1</name>
             </row>
        </RowSet>
       </data>
```

Hope that clarifies. For further API information check the link
http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/portletfactory/8.5.0/WEFABD002/en_us/api/index.html?overview-summary.html